# "Take the initiative to INFINITIVE" vs "Take the initiative of GERUND"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, gerund-vs-infinitive, is-it-a-rule, predicate-frames

Should I say

> Happy I finally took the initiative *to bring* two bottles.

or

> Happy I finally took the initiative *of bringing* two bottles.

Is there a "universal" rule with the phrase "take the initiative to/of"?

Comment: Hello, FMPF. Which do the [McGraw Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/took+the+initiative) and Farlex license? And [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initiative) (The John Barth, Atlantic, March 1995 quote)? And note that there are other possibilities; I'd use << Happily she finally took the initiative and brought two bottles. >> here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no “universal” rule here. One can study the frequencies with which the various possibilities occur within various corpora, but when one does that, one discovers that nothing is black and white here, and that comparative occurrences have shifted over time without any choice wholly eclipsing the rest.

In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), we find the following comparative frequencies (normalized to fall below 100 and above 0):

| phrase | % freq |
| --- | --- |
| take the initiative *in* | 64 |
| take the initiative *on* | 13 |
| take the initiative *to* | 5 |
| take the initiative *for* | 5 |
| take the initiative *of* | 3 |

Which for your sentence would yield:

64. Happy I finally took the initiative **in** bringing two bottles.

13. Happy I finally took the initiative **on** bringing two bottles.

5. Happy I finally took the initiative **to** bring two bottles.

5. Happy I finally took the initiative **for** bringing two bottles.

3. Happy I finally took the initiative **of** bringing two bottles.

If you poke into the surrounding context, however, you'll find that most of these with preposition do not take gerund complements in their citations, which means this is a little misleading taken at face value:

[image: COCA contexts]

However, those are hardly the only possibilities. For example, *by* plus the gerund also works here.

- Happy I finally took the initiative **by** bringing two bottles.

But a more common solution is to use two finite verbs joined by *and*:

- Happy I finally **took the initiative *and* brought** two bottles.

Indeed, if one examines [a few Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+the+initiative+in%2Ctake+the+initiative+and%2Ctake+the+initiative+on%2Ctake+the+initiative+to%2Ctake+the+initiative+of&year_start=1820&year_end=2010&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), one sees how common the *and* solution is:

[image: Google Ngram]

Personally, I might well elect the double finite-verb solution with *and*, at least if I gave it some thought. But those other common versions would also work, and be completely unremarkable. There are no absolute “rules” in these cases.

Answer (score -1):

Take the  initiative in + ing and take the initiative to + infinitive are the more common constructions:

See also [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Take%20the%20initiative%20in%2Ctake%20the%20initiative%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) usage examples.

> PREP. ~ in - She took the initiative in asking the board to conduct an enquiry.

(Oxford Collocation Dictionary )